# Convert oracle code to hive to get variable from unix shell script to hive

Tags: hive, sh, hql, hiveql, hadoop2

Following is the query: 
Oracle procedure query:

`Select col_nam into VAR from table where <conditions....> ;`--- this brings the value into the variable which is then consumed by a function which uses it like...

```
select colnam from tablename where variable2>VAR;
```

Now how can be pull the value from the hive table to VAR variable in hive?

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you could have a table (`table`) with a single row and a single column (`col_nam`) holding your variable.

Then, you can do a Cartesian product join (a join with no conditions) so that each row in the second table where you want to use your variable would get that single column from the `table` table:

`select colnam from tablename,table where variable2>col_nam;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in hive:

1. Create table VAR, it will have only one row and two columns. First column is used for join which can have any static value and second is value column, which store value of VAR in your case.

   create table VAR as select 'xyz' as static,  col_nam as value from table where ...

   [image: VAR]
2. Add a static column in table you want to filter records.

   create table tmp as select p.*,'xyz' as static from realtable;
3. Filter Records-

   select *
   from tmp t join VAR v on t.static=v.static
   where t.variable2>v.value;